# XML File with JAXB Annotation and unknown content

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, config, element

I have a central xml configuration in an Commons project. This means in this project I don´t know which xml elements in the config exists. I want to hold the root element in the configuration. The requestet configuration item from other project has to be with a class object. This class object contains neccessary information of the requestet xml Element with the jaxb annotation. Is it possible to get a filled object from JAXB with this guidelines?

I have no code examples because I don´t know yet how to start.

Answer (score 0):

JAXB mapps the XML structure into Object oriented graph/hierarchy.

**If you don't know the structure/hierarchy of XML, you should use push/pull parsing SAX, StAX, ...**

Comment: In my Configuration Object I want to hold the Root Element. There exist a method like this:

Comment: Why would you do it? If you don't know the structure, JAXB will not map the structure so even if you would hold the Root Element it is not useful.

Comment: In my Configuration Object I want to hold the Root Element. There exist a method like this : public <T> getElement(Class<T> element). The Configuration reads the element due the annotation from the Class Object. Could JAXB build this Object or have i to build it for my own?